# Cannot redeclare conenect() error using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I´m using pdo for my sql statements.
I have a connect.php file with this code:

```
<?php

function connect()
{
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = '';
$dbName = 'mysite';

    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$dbName};host={$dbHost}", $dbUser, $dbPass);
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();

    }
    return $pdo;
    }
 ?>
```

Now Im trying to use my connect.php in other php file like this:

```
include('../crud/config.php');
$pdo = connect();
```

And Im having this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connect() (previously declared in F:\Xampp\htdocs\projet\crud\config.php:9) in F:\Xampp\htdocs\projet\crud\config.php on line 32
```

Somebody there have some ideia why this is happening?

Maybe its because im using the statement like this with $pdo->

```
$verifyLevel = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM administradores where id = :user");  
           $verifyLevel->bindValue(":user", $user);  
           $verifyLevel->execute();
               $num_rows = $verifyLevel->rowCount();
           $result = $verifyLevel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Because if I remove the $pdo = connect(); dont gives thar error but then gives other error but then because Im using $pdo->prepare to my sql statement I have an error because $pdo is not recognized without $pdo = connect()

Comment: check if connect() is defined 2 times in your file !!

Comment: No..I only have 1 time!

Comment: `connect()` may be a core function. Try using a different name.

Comment: Yes, `connect` is predefined in another class. Change `connect` to something different

Comment: Why not just require_once instead of include ?

Comment: I put here connect to translate for english, because my name here is not really connect..so I guess its not that the problem!

Comment: Or try as already stated or `include_once('../crud/config.php');` or `require_once('../crud/config.php');`

Comment: With require_once I Have this error: Undefined variable: pdo that I use to my statment like $pdo->prepare()...